# Thin Restart error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

Hello I am fixing a ruby on rails web server and I am having issues with the thin gem.  I looked on here and bing for help but got lost pretty fast and I was wondering if anyone here knew what was going wrong with my gem.  The error I got after running "thin restart -s 2" is:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:129:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3001.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:111:in `kill'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:94:in `block in stop'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:135:in `tail_log'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:93:in `stop'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in 'run_command'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This is my first time useing the tin gem and I can only guess what is wrong.  I will keep looking and thanks to anyone who knows what is wrong.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep thin` and `kill` all the process and start it again.

Comment: And give `kill -9 PID` to kill all the processes.Restart it again.

Comment: I got:
ps -ef | grep thin
root     25436 25291  0 16:45 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto thin

Comment: I tried to kill -9 PID 25436 but I don't know if I did that right, I will keep trying thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it by starting thin with `thin start`.

`thin restart` means basically `thin stop && thin start`. In my case `thin stop` returned an error because thin wasn't running, therefore could not be stopped.

Comment: when I ran just "thin start" I get this error:::/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: adding bundle exec starts my server on my terminal, I need my servers to be running on the ssh so that the site is live all the time. I will keep at it=D and thanks Bonifacio2! we are close I know it;)

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec thin start`?

Comment: yes that is what I am talking about in my comments. Sorry I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and didn't understand why it failed on `stop` and `restart` (start worked). 
I figured it out having a look to my remote `current/tmp` folder to see if it contained a `pids/` folder. It was missing. So the server can start, but can't stop because the pid is missing.

Sometimes it's missing because your `.gitignore` contains `tmp/*`
Now I have :

```
tmp/cache/*
tmp/data/*
tmp/pids/*
tmp/sessions/*
tmp/sockets/*
```

Folder exists, so PID file can be written, read, and deleted.

Note that if you use Capistrano, you will have to make sure that tmp/pids is symlynked to the shared folder.
Otherwise, cap will write a pid on start in a version, and will try to find these pids in another version, where they won't be, except if you have correct symlink:

```
## Capistrano 3 - deploy.rb
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/backup tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle}
```